# Internet Explorer Application Compatibility VPC Images sha256sums

Tags: linux, internet-explorer

If anyone has these downloaded, or if anyone wants to download them, could you please verify if these are the sha25sums of the files?

sha256sums: http://pastebin.com/zhrjttJc

These were downloaded from: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=11575

I've been having trouble extracting them:

```
$ unrar Windows_Vista_IE7.part06.rar

unrar 0.0.1  Copyright (C) 2004  Ben Asselstine, Jeroen Dekkers


Extracting from /home/yano/.ievms/vhd/IE7/Windows_Vista_IE7.part06.rar

Extracting  Windows Vista.vhd                                         Failed    
Extracting  Windows Vista.vmc                                         Failed    
2 Failed
```

and:

```
$ unrar Windows_Vista_IE7.part01.exe

unrar 0.0.1  Copyright (C) 2004  Ben Asselstine, Jeroen Dekkers


Extracting from /home/yano/.ievms/vhd/IE7/Windows_Vista_IE7.part01.exe

unknown archive type, only plain RAR 2.0 supported(normal and solid archives), SFX and Volumes are NOT supported!
All OK
```

I've been following instructions based on the project ievms over at Github: https://github.com/xdissent/ievms
I've also gone through their issue list for the error messages and they said it was the download links were bad and this was months ago. I'm starting to think my downloads are corrupted, even though I've downloaded these twice already. Any ideas?

Comment: Your trying to unrar a Windows PE executable on Linux of IE? That makes no sense. If you want to test something in IE on Linux, you can't. IE doesn't run on Linux. You did notice that you downloaded the version for Windows Vista, right? Or are you trying to use Wine?

Comment: I'm trying to use the script ievms ( https://github.com/xdissent/ievms ) to create VirtualBox images of the .vhd that are suppose to be extracted from the .rar files.

Comment: Why aren't you using the way he does it? The script downloads it for you.

Comment: I have been trying the script but the error I get above is from running the script and from trying to do the command he does in the script manually.

Comment: How long ago did you install `unrar`?

Comment: Just the other day, I'm use the latest unrar-free from Debian's repositories. » unrar --version
unrar 0.0.1

Comment: Anything that is at version 0.0.1 can't be that stable. Can't you find a Mac or Win macine to try unzipping it on? See if the archive is actually good? I'm on a Mac right now, I can check if you'll give me the archive link.

Comment: Not really, but I could try to get hold of a mac if need be. https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=11575 Windows_Vista_IE7.part01.exe through Windows_Vista_IE7.part06.rar

Comment: I ended up creating VMs using VirtualBox from copies of Windows purchased from Microsoft.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem using unrar-free. remove and install unrar ("UNRAR 4.00 beta 3 freeware" worked for me on Ubuntu 12.04).